# Apache SSL redirect to main folder

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I have the following website structure

```
/var/www/
   |
   |--> home/
          |
          |--> index.html
```

in /etc/apache2/sites-enables/000-default the http virtual host is so configured

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Redirect permanent / https://192.168.17.73/
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to `192.168.17.73/home/index.html` I'm correctly redirected to `https://192.168.17.73/home/index.html`.

However, when I type, `192.168.17.73/home/` the redirection brings me to `https://192.168.17.73/home/home/`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: What happens if you access `https://192.168.17.73/home/` directly? Are you also redirected to `https://192.168.17.73/home/home/`?

Comment: @CélineAussourd no. I get `https://192.168.17.73/home/index.html`

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file in /var/www/?

Comment: @CélineAussourd no, nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended to be a problem caused by a gedit preference to create a backup copy and autosave the files.

**Solution**. After disabling those two features, I deleted any file like httpd.conf.save or httpd.conf~ and all worked fine.